# (Gnome) "To do" app display artifacts and issues

Tags: gnome, graphics, display

I am using a standard Ubuntu 18.04 (fresh install), and have a problem with the bundled ["To Do" application](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Todo) ("gnome-todo").

When I "toggle" an item, I get these graphic artifacts:

[image: to-do-artifacts]

And if I open the app with one of the items toggled open, there is no background for the task panel:

[image: to-do-blank-background]

I don't know if this is the same [bug already reported](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-todo/issues/169) -- I don't think it is -- but wonder whether this is "just me", or whether others get this behaviour, or if there is some further diagnostic I can run to get this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.
The solution for me was to change the applications theme from Ambiance to Adwaita via GNOME Tweaks.
Both Ambiance and Radiance themes create these artifacts in GNOME apps for some reason.

Comment: Thanks - helpful to know. I had given up using this app, but on the back of your answer, I checked it again. And now ... working. Version of ToDo is 3.28.1; annoyed I forgot to add the version as it was in my original post (but probably the same, as that was [already the current version](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-todo/releases) in May 2018).